# Combine Date from one datetime field with Time from another

Tags: apex, trigger, datetime

I have tried all sorts of proposed solutions but can't seem to find one that works. I receive 2 DateTime fields from an api call and need to take the Date part from one and combine it with the Time part from the other in my upsert trigger into a datetime field.

> datetime dtime = opp.AccModifiedTime__c; //1899-12-30 15:38:19
>
> datetime ddate = opp.AccModifiedDate__c; //2014-08-13 00:00:00

It also seems to save these as GMT time when coming in via the API, which is not what I want - this is the local correct time and I want it to display as such. It will display the hours as 3:38 AM (I'm in NZ, so it's 12hrs before GMT). I need it to display as a datetime field of

> 13/08/2014 03:38 PM

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `Datetime.newInstance` [method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_newInstance_2) with parameters `Date, Time`.

```
Datetime withDate; // e.g. 2014-08-13 00:00:00
Datetime withTime; // e.g. 1899-12-30 15:38:19

Datetime withBoth = Datetime.newInstance(withDate.date(), withTime.time());
```

If you wanted to preserve GMT (doesn't sound that way) you could use `withTime.timeGMT()`.

Comment: Thanks Adrian! Works perfectly. I had to use the .timeGMT() in order for it to store it as a GMT time, so it would display it at local time.